# How to start over a count

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am trying to keep a 1-10 count and if the count goes over 10 it starts back at 1

```
Tick := 5;
currentTick := 8;
```

Now `FinalTick` is going to be CurrentTick + Tick but once the value is 10 it should stat over at 1 thus in this case

5 + 8 = 3

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want count to be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4 etc, you can:

```
procedure IncCount(var ACount: Integer);
begin
  ACount := (ACount + 1) mod 10;
end;
```

If you want count to be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4 etc, you can:

```
procedure IncCount(var ACount: Integer);
begin
  ACount := ACount mod 10 + 1;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks never knew about this Modulo Operator

Answer (score 5):

I would use the so called modulo operator ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

> FinalTick := ( CurrentTick + Tick ) mod 10;

Comment: "if the count goes over 10 it starts back at 1"

So add *if FinalTick = 0 then FinalTick := 10;*

Answer (score 3):

You should use modulo operator, such as

```
Val:=(5+8) mod 10
```

Answer (score 2):

MOD operator is a solution as most answers here.

Sometimes this may help:

```
procedure Foo;
var I: Integer;
begin
  I := 0;
  repeat
    I := I + 1;
    // Do your stuff here
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(I));
    // Add some exit conition, like:
    // if (..) then break;
    if I = 10 then I := 0;
  until False;
end;
```